# How to install PyGears on WSL - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pygears

Is there any instruction on how to install PyGears from scratch on WSL? I tried to find it online but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

WSL is quite new, and it's quite different than standard Ubuntu. It usually comes without some of the packages and there is always the chance that something is missing and that it should be added additionally.

Here is the process that worked for me:

**WSL 2 installation**

[LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

**Build essential**

To be able to run all PyGears tools we need to be sure we have all essentials installed, run next commands to get it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

**Text editor**

WSL is coming without standard text editor like gedit for example. Install something that you are used to. Have in mind that for gedit you will need some kind of server to be able to show gedit as a GUI  app.

**GUI on WSL 2**

I will also cover this topic, just to make sure you got everything right. To be able to see GUI in WSL you can install this tool [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/). After installation run XLaunch with these settings:

- Display settings: Multiple windows, Display number = -1
- Client startup: Start no client
- Extra settings: check all boxes and leave "Additional parameters" empty

I know it's not super safe. This allows WSL2 to connect properly though, per [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4106) and [this Github](https://github.com/hubisan/emacs-wsl#configure-wsl). Note that you'll have to add the export to .bashrc

```
export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0
```

(or some variant of it), to your .bashrc, so that  WSL2 finds the proper display.

If this solution doesn’t work please check [this link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242).

To test is GUI working type

```
source ~/.bashrc
echo $DISPLAY
```

And something like this should be seen: `172.31.0.1:0`

**Installing PyGears**

Install with pip
First, make sure that you have pip installed

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

PyGears requires Python 3.6 or higher. Install PyGears package with the command below.

```
sudo pip3 install -U pygears-tools
```

Next, type this command

```
pygears-tools-install -d
```

Now, WSL 2 isn’t coming by default with xcb plugin for Qt, to solve this issue type next:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0
```

That should be it. For testing purpose you can use this code:

```python
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Ufixp, Uint
from pygears.lib import drv, collect
from pygears.sim import sim, cosim


@gear
def darken(din, *, gain):
    return din * Ufixp[0, 8](gain)


res = []

drv(t=Uint[8], seq=[12, 23, 255]) \
    | darken(gain=0.5) \
    | float \
    | collect(result=res)

cosim('/darken', 'verilator', outdir='./home/stefan/test/output')
sim()

print(res)
```

Change `outdir` to show somewhere in your space and save file as .py and compile as standard python file. Output should be something like:

```
-          /darken/mul [INFO]: Running sim with seed: 2631661647950327284
0                      [INFO]: -------------- Simulation start --------------
103                    [INFO]: ----------- Simulation done ---------------
103                    [INFO]: Elapsed: 0.01
[6.0, 11.5, 127.5]
```

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf doesn't work this way on new Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Comment: Hey, @MajesticRa we tested it on Ubuntu 20.04 a few months ago on a couple of machines and all worked flawlessly. Let me know what is a problem or error that you are getting so I can help.

Comment: I have a windows preview, now wsl IP isn't changing and /etc/resolv.conf looks differently and nameserver points to my router's IP. But it happened only when I installed fresh Ubuntu 20.04, everything works the same as before on existing 18.04