# How can I use GearBox in pyGears framework?

Tags: pygears

I was wondering how to run GearBox, is there any command or anything?
I checked website [www.pygears.org](https://pygears.org) but there are no information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this, if you are using Linux first make sure you have GearBox installed, just type

```
gearbox
```

in your terminal. After you run it you should get windows like this
[image]

If that's what you got, you should be okay to proceed with the command

```
gearbox <python_file>
```

<python_file> should be your top level python file.

Yet, if GearBox is not running please check these answers for installation:

- [How to install PyGears on WSL - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938574/how-to-install-pygears-on-wsl-ubuntu-20-04-lts)
- [How to install PyGears on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64279659/how-to-install-pygears-on-linux)